# How to add data vertically while xtracting tables from web page to excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

My code

```
Public Sub Raju()         
Dim alertTime As Date
alertTime = Now + TimeValue("0:05:00")        
'
' mymacro Macro        
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")  
Dim usedRows As Long
usedRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row     
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _"URL", Destination _:=ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(usedRows, 1)))
```

Now table updated in horizontal direction
but i need vertically.

Comment: Post your solution if you've solved it